# Passing ffmpeg command containing % through Python subprocess

Tags: python, ffmpeg, subprocess

I'm trying to build a GUI with Tkinter where a set of images is converted, via press of a button, to an .mp4 video.

When I run the following from the command line, all is well:

```
> "ffmpeg -r 5 -i ptimage%03d -crf 20 animation.mp4"
```

However, in Python, the following gives me an error that I think is related to passing the `%` in the argument:

```
commandString = "ffmpeg -r 5 -i ptimage%03d -crf 20 animation.mp4"
args = shlex.split(commandString)
p = subprocess.run(args)
```

The error I get is `ptimage%03d: No such file or directory`. I'm 99% sure I'm running the command from the right directory; when I run the same command replacing `ptimage%03d` with `ptimage000.jpg`, a specific image the list, I get a (really short) video successfully.

I've tried escaping the `%` with `\%`, but that doesn't help.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you are in the correct folder? What does `os.getcwd()` show?

Comment: Is the name of your file really `ptimage%03d`? That's a very unusual name for a file. subprocess isn't going to expand metacharacters for you.

Comment: With `ptimage%03d` it is expecting files named `ptimage000`,`ptimage001`, `ptimage002`, etc. Maybe you meant to use `ptimage%03d.jpg` for `ptimage000.jpg`, `ptimage001.jpg`, etc.

Comment: As an aside, -- in general, it's better practice to write out your command as a list instead of relying on `shlex.split()` a string for you.

Comment: ...focusing on the question at hand, though: no, `%`s aren't special unless you're using the formatting operator; there's nothing Python is doing here that would munge your name, so the comments above suggesting user error (incorrect directory, or that it should be `ptimage%03d.jpg` with the extension) are the most plausible explanation coming at this from a direction of Python expertise but only moderate familiarity with ffmpeg usage.

Comment: @llogan Ugh. Yes, I'm missing the `.jpg`. Thought I had copy/pasted straight from the command line, but I guess I didn't.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Noted. Was following a tutorial about using `subprocess`, and while it didn't seem all that necessary, I decided to just use it. Abandoning it would remove one other source of uncertainty, in retrospect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You omitted the file extension. Use `ptimage%03d.jpg`, not `ptimage%03d`. With `ptimage%03d` ffmpeg is expecting files named `ptimage000` ,`ptimage001`, etc.

```
ffmpeg -framerate 5 -i ptimage%03d.jpg -crf 20 animation.mp4
```

---

<sub>Unrelated notes: Some players (YouTube excluded) can't handle such a low frame, so consider adding the `-r 10` output option. Same with the chroma subsampling: consider adding `-vf format=yuv420p` output option.</sub>